# Kotlin // Solve the example in a line

Tags: kotlin

How to solve an example in a string?
Let's say we have `val example : String = "3+5"`

So how do I solve this example? Or if `val example : String = "3*5/3"`

Comment: There's no built-in way to do this in the Kotlin standard library. You need to either parse the text yourself, or find an arithmetic library you can use.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I'm not quite versed in using third party libraries. could you help me? I know how it works in python. And I don’t know how it works in Kotlin. I write in android studio.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-android-studio When you find a library you want to use, usually on Github, they usually show you what line to put for `implementation` in the readme.

Comment: I like `implementation "net.objhunter:exp4j:0.4.8"`, documentation here: https://www.objecthunter.net/exp4j/ The documentation is in Java, but pretty easy to convert to Kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to achieve it:

1. **[Keval - 3rd party dependency](https://github.com/notKamui/Keval)**

   You can either use `Keval.eval("(3+4)(2/8 * 5) % PI")` or as an extension function on `String`, `"(3+4)(2/8 * 5) % PI".keval()`. This will return the calculated value as `Double`. For your example, `"3*5/3".keval()`.

   To use it, add `implementation("com.notkamui.libs:keval:0.8.0")` in dependencies in app level `build.gradle` file and sync gradle. Then, use it in any file as mentioned in the above para, put the cursor on the line and press `Alt + Enter` (or hover for suggestions) to import the necessary imports.

   Look into its Readme.md on the provided link for more usage and implementation details.
2. **Custom String parsing using BODMAS rule**

   You can split the string using the BODMAS rule, parse the split array as `int`/`double`, if it throws exception, it means the substring is an expression too, again split it using BODMAS, parse and perform the calculation.